# Facebook Login via Firebase - Access_Token_Denied Error

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-authentication

Facebook logs in correctly. In the Firebase console, I can see the user has logged. However,  I cannot access any of the user's info.

I am getting below error log in LogCat:

> signInWithFacebook:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED
>   permissions:[public_profile, contact_email, user_friends, email]}

Afterwards, I also receive a FirebaseError: Permission denied in the LogCat and as a toast inside the app.

Following this [tutorial](http://androidbash.com/firebase-classic-email-login-facebook-login-android), I have made a project that integrates Facebook and Firebase. I've tried copy and pasting the source code, and replacing the necessary lines (such as Facebook ID and Firebase URL) but it isn't working for me.

here is the specific void

```
private void signInWithFacebook(AccessToken token) {
Log.d(TAG, "signInWithFacebook:" + token.getToken());

showProgressDialog();


AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    String uid=task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                    String name=task.getResult().getUser().getDisplayName();
                    String email=task.getResult().getUser().getEmail();
                    String image=task.getResult().getUser().getPhotoUrl().toString();

                     //Create a new User and Save it in Firebase database
                    User user = new User(uid,name,null,email,name);

                    mRef.child(uid).setValue(user);

                    Log.d(TAG, uid);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("user_id",uid);
                    intent.putExtra("profile_picture",image);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        });
}
```

here is the full code

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "AndroidBash";
public User user;
private EditText email;
private EditText password;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
//Add YOUR Firebase Reference URL instead of the following URL
private Firebase mRef=new Firebase("https://firebase.firebaseio.com");

//FaceBook callbackManager
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
//

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (mUser != null) {
        // User is signed in
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        String image=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString();
        intent.putExtra("user_id", uid);
        if(image!=null || image!=""){
            intent.putExtra("profile_picture",image);
        }
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + mUser.getUid());
    }

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser mUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (mUser != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + mUser.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }

        }
    };

    //FaceBook
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            signInWithFacebook(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
        }
    });
    //
   }
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_email_id);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_password);
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}


//FaceBook
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
//

protected void setUpUser() {
    user = new User();
    user.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
    user.setPassword(password.getText().toString());
}

public void onSignUpClicked(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onLoginClicked(View view) {
    setUpUser();
    signIn(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
}

private void signIn(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "signIn:" + email);
    if (!validateForm()) {
        return;
    }

    showProgressDialog();

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        intent.putExtra("user_id", uid);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            });
    //
}

private boolean validateForm() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String userEmail = email.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail)) {
        email.setError("Required.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        email.setError(null);
    }

    String userPassword = password.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword)) {
        password.setError("Required.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        password.setError(null);
    }

    return valid;
}


private void signInWithFacebook(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithFacebook:" + token.getToken());

    showProgressDialog();


    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        String uid=task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                        String name=task.getResult().getUser().getDisplayName();
                        String email=task.getResult().getUser().getEmail();
                        String image=task.getResult().getUser().getPhotoUrl().toString();

                         //Create a new User and Save it in Firebase database
                        User user = new User(uid,name,null,email,name);

                        mRef.child(uid).setValue(user);

                        Log.d(TAG, uid);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("user_id",uid);
                        intent.putExtra("profile_picture",image);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            });
}


public void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

public void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you added the HASH Key in the fb dev console?

Comment: Yes, I made sure the HASH, Facebook ID were all accurate. My Facebook console says I am logged in, however, the app is denied any permissions to access the user's data.